# Using wildfly CLI can I increase the transaction timeout at application level?

Tags: java, wildfly, jta, wildfly-10

I know that using CLI interface I can increase the default transaction tiemout `/subsystem=transactions:write-attribute(name=default-timeout,value=500)`.

However, I would wish to do this for a specific session bean method of my deployment. Is this possible via CLI? I use CMT.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a transaction timeout using an annotation:

```
@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout(value=500, unit=TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

It is applicable at method and type level.

Or you switch to BMT and use `javax.transaction.TransactionManager#setTransactionTimeout(int)`.

Comment: Than you for providing an answer. The question was different though. I wonder whether this is possible through wildfly CLI (command line interface).